# How i change the buttons color on a ahk script when the button is pressed and changed back to the default white

Tags: autohotkey

How i change the buttons color on a ahk script when the button is pressed and changed back to the default white when the same button is pressed again? The color doesnt matter, I only care that the orignal color is white, then when the button is pressed, the color of the button changes. Once the button is pressed again, the button color should revert to the defualt white. Sorry if it feels like im going in circles.
Here is the original code without the color changing attempts

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force

; Get a list of all Roblox windows
WinGet, robloxid, list, ahk_exe RobloxPlayerBeta.exe

Gui +hwndMyGui
Gui Add, Button, x10 y10 w200 h30 gButton1, Roblox 1
Gui Add, Button, x10 y50 w200 h30 gButton2, Roblox 2
Gui Add, Button, x10 y90 w200 h30 gButton3, Roblox 3
Gui Add, Button, x10 y130 w200 h30 gButton4, Roblox 4
Gui Add, Button, x10 y170 w200 h30 gButton5, Roblox 5
Gui Add, Button, x10 y210 w200 h30 gButton6, Roblox 6
Gui Add, Button, x10 y250 w200 h30 gButton7, Roblox 7
Gui Add, Button, x10 y290 w200 h30 gButton8, Roblox 8
Gui Show, x200 y200 h350 w220, Roblox Buttons

Return

GuiClose:
ExitApp
Return

Button1:
WinActivate ahk_id %robloxid1%
Return

Button2:
WinActivate ahk_id %robloxid2%
Return

Button3:
WinActivate ahk_id %robloxid3%
Return

Button4:
WinActivate ahk_id %robloxid4%
Return

Button5:
WinActivate ahk_id %robloxid5%
Return

Button6:
WinActivate ahk_id %robloxid6%
Return

Button7:
WinActivate ahk_id %robloxid7%
Return

Button8:
WinActivate ahk_id %robloxid8%
Return
```

```
MyGui:
Gui, Add, Button, x20 y20 w120 h40 gButton1 vButton1, Roblox 1
Gui, Add, Button, x150 y20 w120 h40 gButton2 vButton2, Roblox 2
Gui, Add, Button, x280 y20 w120 h40 gButton3 vButton3, Roblox 3
Gui, Add, Button, x410 y20 w120 h40 gButton4 vButton4, Roblox 4

Gui, Show, w600 h100, My Gui

return

Button1Color := "Red"
Button2Color := "Red"
Button3Color := "Red"
Button4Color := "Red"

Button1Count := 0
Button2Count := 0
Button3Count := 0
Button4Count := 0

Button1:
  Button1Count += 1
  GuiControl, MyGui, Text, % (toggleButtonColor("Button1Color") ? "Button1 clicked" : "Roblox 1")
  return

Button2:
  Button2Count += 1
  GuiControl, MyGui, Text, % (toggleButtonColor("Button2Color") ? "Button2 clicked" : "Roblox 2")
  return

Button3:
  Button3Count += 1
  GuiControl, MyGui, Text, % (toggleButtonColor("Button3Color") ? "Button3 clicked" : "Roblox 3")
  return

Button4:
  Button4Count += 1
  GuiControl, MyGui, Text, % (toggleButtonColor("Button4Color") ? "Button4 clicked" : "Roblox 4")
  return

toggleButtonColor(buttonColor) {
  if (%buttonColor% = "Red") {
    GuiControl,, %buttonColor%, Green
    return true
  } else {
    GuiControl,, %buttonColor%, Red
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like C++.

Comment: AHK is programmed in C++

Answer (score 1):

---

### Create changeable custom buttons using ahk v1.

---

- Let's just say there aren't many easy ways to do this, so I looked for the simplest and most intuitive way to answer you.
- It is possible to do what you want using an external class. I made a small modification to it, which is in the repository [link](https://github.com/enigma-w-e-b/ImageButtonAhk)
- Code that I believe will be useful for you.

  ```
  Include Class_ImageButton.ahk

  global btn1enable := True ;

  Gui, Margin, 20, 20
  Gui, Font, s11 normal, Segoe UI

  Gui, Add, Button, x10 y10 w200 h40 gBtnFuncA hWnd_BTN_ID_1
  Gui, Add, Button, x10 y55 w200 h40 gBtnFuncB hWnd_BTN_ID_2
  Gui, Add, Button, x10 y100 w200 h40 gBtnFuncC hWnd_BTN_ID_3
  Gui, Add, Button, x10 y145 w200 h40 gBtnFuncD hWnd_BTN_ID_4

  EStyle := [[0, 0x80F0F0F0, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x8046B8DA, 2] ; normal
    , [0, 0x80C6E9F4, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x8046B8DA, 2] ; hover
    , [0, 0x8086D0E7, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x8046B8DA, 2] ; pressed
    , [0, 0x80F0F0F0, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x8046B8DA, 2]]

  DStyle := [[0, 0x80F0F0F0, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x80D43F3A, 2] ; normal
    , [0, 0x80F0B9B8, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x80D43F3A, 2] ; hover
    , [0, 0x80E27C79, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x80D43F3A, 2] ; pressed
    , [0, 0x80F0F0F0, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x80D43F3A, 2]]

  WStyle := [ [0, 0x80F0F0F0, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x80F0AD4E, 2] ; normal
    , [0, 0x80FCEFDC, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x80F0AD4E, 2] ; hover
    , [0, 0x80F6CE95, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x80F0AD4E, 2] ; pressed
    , [0, 0x80F0F0F0, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x80F0AD4E, 2] ]

  SStyle := [ [0, 0x80F0F0F0, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x805CB85C, 2] ; normal
      , [0, 0x80C6E6C6, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x805CB85C, 2] ; hover
      , [0, 0x8091CF91, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x805CB85C, 2] ; pressed
      , [0, 0x80F0F0F0, , , 8, 0xFFF0F0F0, 0x805CB85C, 2] ]

  ImageButton.Create(_BTN_ID_1,"BTN TESTE 1 [ A ]", EStyle*) ; define o                                                                   estilo inicial
  ImageButton.Create(_BTN_ID_2,"BTN TESTE 2", EStyle*) ; define o estilo inicial
  ImageButton.Create(_BTN_ID_3,"BTN TESTE 3", WStyle*) ; define o estilo inicial
  ImageButton.Create(_BTN_ID_4,"BTN TESTE 4", SStyle*) ; define o estilo inicial

  Gui Show, w220 h200, Image Buttons
  return

  BtnFuncA:
      if (btn1enable) {
        ImageButton.Create(_BTN_ID_1, "BTN TESTE 1 [ D ]", DStyle*)
        btn1enable := False
      } else {
        ImageButton.Create(_BTN_ID_1, "BTN TESTE 1 [ A ]", EStyle*)
        btn1enable := True
      }
  return

  BtnFuncB:
  BtnFuncC:
  BtnFuncD:
  ```
- [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZdPw.png) | [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud3DL.png)